# Import a Python library from Github

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, github, ipython

I'm new to Python so this may sound silly.

I want to use a Python library I've found on Github, lets say on `https://github.com/praw-dev/praw`, and I want to be able to do `git pull` in the future to pull the latest commits.

**Question:** Should I `git clone <git url>` in the project directory and delete everything except the `praw` directory, then in my python script do a `import praw`?

In iPython,

```
import praw
```

gives the error `ImportError: No module named praw`

**Directory Structure**

```
~\myProject\
    praw\
    myNotebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 52):

Actually, if given package is not on PyPI (or you want a specific branch) you can still install it through pip from GitHub with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/[repo owner]/[repo]@[branch name]
```

And for your problem it would be (although @pandita's answer is correct for normal usage case):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/praw-dev/praw.git
```

For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/2351523) answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have a github repo named pinyin_utils. Executing the command - replacing [repo owner] with my github user name and [repo] with 'pinyin_utils' or 'pinyin_utils.git', [branch name] with 'master', or leaving it and the '@' off, I get the error message: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\{{User}}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-yk2dkge1\\setup.py'
(NOTE: I replaced by local user name with {{User}} - the folders exist up to and including 'Temp') Doing this in a PowerShell window with admin privileges.

Comment: Note for anyone stumbling on this, this works as long as there is either a `setup.py` file or a `pyproject.toml` file in the directory.

Answer (score 20):

Experimental Python module finder/loader from github, like in golang.

So, in golang we can import like:

```
import "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"
```

But in python we should install package by our hands:

```
pip install requests
```

And import it like:

```
import requests
```

But with this magic package and power of PEP-0302 we can do it automatically:

```
from github_com.kennethreitz import requests

assert requests.get('https://github.com/nvbn/import_from_github_com').status_code == 200
```

**Installation**

You should have git, Python 3.2+ and pip:

```
pip install import_from_github_com
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/nvbn/import_from_github_com

Answer (score 10):

Just clone the files in any dir on your python path and then build the lib typically with `python setup.py install` from the command line.

I typically clone a libray form git in my `site_libraries` folder ( the folder that holds all of your pip installed packages ). From there you can pull and then build the libraries from git just like any other git repo. Having the files there is nice because all of your libs are in once place on your python path.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using `pip` instead of git to install and upgrade the package (that is unless you have a pressing reason to use git).

`pip install praw`

to update the package you can do

`pip install --upgrade praw`

Also have a look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for further information on how to use pip.

Comment: The question wants it 'from github'