# pip install from git repo branch

Tags: python, git, pip

Trying to `pip` install a repo's specific branch. Google tells me to

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch
```

The branch's name is `issue/34/oscar-0.6` so I did `pip  install https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@/issue/34/oscar-0.6` but its returning a 404.

How do I install this branch?

Comment: to me your suggestion work e.g. `pip install https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch` doing `pip install -U git+https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git@dev` worked. Perhaps remove the extra `/`?

Answer (score 1527, accepted):

Prepend the url prefix `git+` (See [VCS Support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/)):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6
```

And specify the branch name without the leading `/`.

Comment: is it mendatory to specify branch or commit by `@` ?

Comment: @eugene, No, `@` and parts after that is optional.

Comment: @SalahAdDin, I don't understand what you mean by `tree`. The given command in the answer works fine : http://i.imgur.com/5q9F0CC.png

Comment: Is for branches, for example: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/danreeves/wagtailgmaps@3.0.0`

Comment: @SalahAdDin, The command you gave works fine. http://i.imgur.com/YtzNvMF.png  Could you explain more?

Comment: I've done this, but there's only 6 text files in the `python/lib/site-packages/my_module` folder. I'd expect there to be the full source code straight from the github repo.

Comment: On a related note, how do you switch between branches i.e., dev back to master branch?

Comment: @Kambiz, `issue/34/oscar-0.6` is a branch name as mentioned in the question. Replace that with `master` / `dev` as you want. 
`pip install git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@master`

Comment: Any idea why I am getting ` Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 ` ?

Comment: Before switching branches, is it recommended to remove the package ... or do anything else before switching?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, `pip install ...` will remove package before update; I don't do anything. Is there anything in mind?

Comment: I want to install the master branch of [jupyter console](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console) and then switch back to normal [pypi jupyter console](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter_console/) when it catches up.  I am just wondering about gotchas lurking beneath the surface.

Comment: You can also put something like this `git+https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-metrics@v3.1.4` into your requirements.txt and then install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will install Tag v3.1.4 from master branch.

Comment: After the first time, is there a precise way to tell `pip` to do a `git pull` to install the latest version of the branch?

Comment: quotes may be required in some cases - in particular if you are installing a certain package from a subdirectory (or adding any additional url params), like : `pip install "git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git#egg=someName&subdirectory=someSubDirectory"`

Comment: Is it normal that after doing this type of install, in `pip list` I am unable to see that a particular package is installed from GiHub, whereas if a package is installed from a local directory, that information is displayed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Do you mean `pip freeze`? https://imgur.com/PlEF9e3

Comment: @falsetru I am not interested in `pip freeze`. I was wondering why `pip list` indicates which packages were installed from local directories but fails to do so for repository packages.

Comment: if i do this with the normal package already installed, how do i import the branch specific version in my python program?

Comment: .git necessary?

Comment: @SmartManoj, `.git` in URL? It originates from the url shown on github clone button click.

Comment: Just copied URL from address bar and it's worked

Answer (score 445):

Using pip with git+ to clone a repository can be extremely slow (test with https://github.com/django/django@stable/1.6.x for example, it will take a few minutes). The fastest thing I've found, which works with GitHub and BitBucket, is:

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repository/archive/branch.zip
```

which becomes for Django master:

```
pip install https://github.com/django/django/archive/master.zip
```

for Django stable/1.7.x:

```
pip install https://github.com/django/django/archive/stable/1.7.x.zip
```

With BitBucket it's about the same predictable pattern:

```
pip install https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/get/default.zip
```

Here, the master branch is generally named default.
This will make your `requirements.txt` installing much faster.

Some other answers mention variations required when placing the package to be installed into your `requirements.txt`.  Note that with this archive syntax, the leading `-e` and trailing `#egg=blah-blah` are *not* required, and you can just simply paste the URL, so your requirements.txt looks like:

```
https://github.com/user/repository/archive/branch.zip
```

Comment: **Note:** from Django 1.9 on, Django ships with a file that has a [unicode filename](https://github.com/django/django/commit/bd059e3f8c6311dcaf8afe5e29ef373f7f84cf26). The zip extractor used by pip chokes on that. An easy workaround is to replace `.zip` with `.tar.gz`, as the tar extractor works.

Comment: I wonder if pip could pass `--depth 0` when cloning to make it more efficient (the entire git history is not needed to install a snapshot for pip). https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: This also works for commit hashes!
`pip install https://github.com/django/django/archive/ebaa08b.zip`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the speed difference. I did not test and compare them, but I believe the speed difference does exist, because installing from a branch would still result in downloading the entire repo history, while installing from a `.zip` (or `.tar.gz`) would result in downloading just a snapshot of the repo.

Comment: Is it possible to install extras using this syntax?  For instance, I'm trying to install https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow @ master (the normal PyPI package is apache-airflow) to work with an unreleased version.  I'd like to convert the call `pip install apache-airflow[crypto, slack]` to install these extras with the archive version.  I tried `pip install https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/archive/master.zip[crypto, slack]` but this breaks the URL and installation.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to be possible when running pip install directly and just requires setting the egg name explicitly - `pip install https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/archive/master.zip#egg=airflow[crypto,slack]`.  Also the spaces between extras in my previous comment are a mistake.  Note that however this syntax with extras _does not_ seem to work in a requirements.txt file.

Comment: Note that despite `pipenv` is rather similar to `pip`, using archives with `pipenv` will not resolve dependencies.

Comment: FWIW using pip 22 the accepted answer was not any slower than this method, and doesn't appear to clone the entire git history of the repo

Comment: Found the .zip  install to be much faster when using repos that contain multiple levels of submodules. Skipping the recursive submodule downloads offers a speed advantage , but may also break dependencies.

Comment: There are reports that recursive dependency installation doesn't work when you use `pipenv` for archives, but [it works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75213065/241211). I think it was [fixed in 2018-09](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/commit/683df2f8ad73e53e9e50364a9cfeb7493a7f1552).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) for adding to `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 185):

Instructions to install from private repo using **ssh credentials**:

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/foo.git@my_version
```

To install a package from a subdirectory, say `stackoverflow`

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/foo.git@my_version#subdirectory=stackoverflow
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/

Comment: Could we get the source/documentation for this? I like this solution.

Comment: I'm not actually sure where I found it.

Comment: @JustinRice The [official documentation for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git) can be a good source.

Answer (score 62):

This worked like charm:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/deepak1725/fabric8-analytics-worker.git@develop
```

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| User | `deepak1725` |
| Repository | `fabric8-analytics-worker` |
| Branch | `develop` |

Answer (score 59):

Just to add an extra, if you want to install it in your pip file it can be added like this:

```
-e git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6#egg=django-oscar-paypal
```

It will be saved as an egg though.

Comment: Better to use it without the `-e`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518202/451710

Comment: Thanks for the comment, very interesting. I think people tend to use the `-e` flag to avoid any possible conflict with an already existent package. I guess is a matter of choice

Comment: And if you want "extras", append them in he fragment, like that: ``-e git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6#egg=django-oscar-paypal[PDF]``

Comment: Note that the `-e` does not actually seem to be required.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for me without the `-e`

Comment: @EyalLevin Better to use it **WITH** the `-e`. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source/34518202#comment76338057_34518202

Answer (score 12):

You used the egg files install procedure.
This procedure supports installing over `git`, `git+http`, `git+https`, `git+ssh`, `git+git` and `git+file`. Some of these are mentioned in other answers.

It's good. You can use branches, tags, or hashes to install.

[Steve_K noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/241211) it can be slow to install with "git+" and proposed installing via zip file:

```bash
pip install https://github.com/user/repository/archive/branch.zip
```

Alternatively, I suggest you may install using the `.whl` file if this exists.

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repository/archive/branch.whl
```

It's pretty new format, newer than egg files. It requires `wheel` and `setuptools>=0.8` packages. You can find more in [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/).

Comment: The question is not specify to github. The notion of an archive/branch.zip is specific to github only.

Answer (score 11):

to me your suggestion from question work e.g.

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch
```

translating concretely to doing

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git@dev
```

worked. Perhaps remove the extra `/` is redundant. My output:

```
(original_anatome_env) brando~/ultimate-anatome ❯ pip install -U git+https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git@dev
Collecting git+https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git@dev
  Cloning https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git (to revision dev) to /private/var/folders/x4/0xq0brj57xz3dbhbmblypbm00000gr/T/pip-req-build-62d_ghd2
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git /private/var/folders/x4/0xq0brj57xz3dbhbmblypbm00000gr/T/pip-req-build-62d_ghd2
  Running command git checkout -b dev --track origin/dev
  Switched to a new branch 'dev'
  Branch 'dev' set up to track remote branch 'dev' from 'origin'.
  Resolved https://github.com/moskomule/anatome.git to commit 4b576e51cb1824a57ea04974e0f92b5a6143294d
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.10.0 in /Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/metalearning/envs/original_anatome_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from anatome==0.0.6) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.11.1 in /Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/metalearning/envs/original_anatome_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from anatome==0.0.6) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/metalearning/envs/original_anatome_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.10.0->anatome==0.0.6) (3.10.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.0,>=5.3.0 in /Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/metalearning/envs/original_anatome_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision>=0.11.1->anatome==0.0.6) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/metalearning/envs/original_anatome_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision>=0.11.1->anatome==0.0.6) (1.21.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: anatome
  Building wheel for anatome (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for anatome: filename=anatome-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl size=10167 sha256=63b12a36f33deb8313bfe7756be60bd08915b8ba36711be47e292b590df70f61
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/x4/0xq0brj57xz3dbhbmblypbm00000gr/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-rde_ngug/wheels/19/e4/be/01479e8cba62ae8cdcd501cd3bf49e199f2bb94732a6a1b006
Successfully built anatome
Installing collected packages: anatome
  Attempting uninstall: anatome
    Found existing installation: anatome 0.0.5
    Uninstalling anatome-0.0.5:
      Successfully uninstalled anatome-0.0.5
Successfully installed anatome-0.0.6
```

0.6.0 is the dev branch version number and 0.5.0 is the master, so it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install optional dependencies when using a direct link to a git repository here is the example:

```
pip install "django[bcrypt] @ git+ssh://git@github.com/django/django.git"
```

Answer (score -2):

> For windows & pycharm setup:

If you are using **pycharm** and If you want to use `pip3 install git+https://github.com/...`

- firstly, you should download git from https://git-scm.com/downloads
- then restart pycharm
- and you can use pycharm terminal to install what you want

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)