# Python / pip, how do I install a specific version of a git repository from github (what is the correct url)?

Tags: python, django, git, github

I want to install Django 1.7 via pip. It is currently a development version, so not in pips repositories.

So I have installed packages from github before using:

```
pip install git+[url here]
```

Now looking at github, I get the clone url on the django page:

```
https://github.com/django/django.git
```

But this mentions nothing of the branch. How do I specify that I want version 1.7? 
Is it somewhere obvious on the github page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip install from github repo branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch)

Comment: not really considering I was asking what the URL should be, and the other user seemed to know that. Though feel free to downvote the question in true overzealous moderator style.

Comment: And that post doesn't tell you anything about the format of the URL, does it not?

Comment: But that wasn't in the question was it, or I may have seen it.

Comment: And doesn't give any helpful advice about being able to use  a branch / commit hash / tag name either.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Specify the **branch**, **commit hash**, or **tag name** after an `@` at the end of the url:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b3
```

This will install the [version tagged with `1.7b3`](https://github.com/django/django/releases/tag/1.7b3).

Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/

Comment: And if you want to put it in your requirements.txt: -e git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.7c1#egg=Django