# No module named changelist_ordering

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import `changelist_ordering`. So I have tried to install the package `django-changelist-ordering`. But I am getting the error:

> No matching distribution found for changelist-ordering

Can anyone help me to solve this issues.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://github.com/SergeyKubrak/django-changelist-ordering)? *How* are you trying to install it?

Comment: using pip command - pip install django-changelist-ordering

Comment: Did you look on PyPI? It doesn't appear to be there (https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=changelist+ordering&submit=search), so you will probably have to install it direct from GitHub.

Comment: Go and find out! But note that the package hasn't been updated in three years, so may not be worth the effort...

Comment: try to download package from https://github.com/SergeyKubrak/django-changelist-ordering/archive/master.zip , unzip it and then install from `Terminal` with `python /path/to/unzipped/django-changelist-ordering-master/setup.py install`

Comment: @Andersson : Got it thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all install `changelist-ordering` by performing the following steps:

- `git clone https://github.com/SergeyKubrak/django-changelist-ordering`
- `cd django-changelist-ordering`
- `sudo python setup.py build`
- `sudo python setup.py install`

or you can install the package by running just one command ([@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510885/no-module-named-changelist-ordering/31513036?noredirect=1#comment50988609_31513036)):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/SergeyKubrak/django-changelist-ordering
```

Now in your projects settings, include the app `changelist_ordering` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

and then wherever you wanna use `ChangeListOrdering` import as

```
from changelist_ordering.admin import ChangeListOrdering
```

If this also does not work for you, check whether the module is installed in your virtual environment or not with

```
pip list | grep changelist-ordering
```

This should get you a result if `changelist-ordering` is present in your virtual environment else your Django application is trying to access the module which is not present in your virtual environment.

Comment: You know `pip` can install directly from a GitHub repo with a `setup.py`?

Comment: I said you could do it, but **that's not how!** See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20101834/3001761