# pip install from bitbucket repo's branch

Tags: python, git, pip, bitbucket

Similar to [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch)

Although, it still does not work. Is it a difference between github and bitbucket?

I'm using the `FROM python:latest` docker image and my dockerfile has `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

My requirements.txt has:

```
-e git+https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3.git@py3#egg=eyed3
```

but it gives the error:

> fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3.git/' not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

eyeD3 is an `hg` repo, not a `git` repo.

Try something similar to this:

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3#egg=eyeD3
```

see https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#mercurial

Comment: FYI: for the dockerfile I had to add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q mercurial`

Comment: It is odd that BitBucket doesn't show you what source control the project is using. I found it by looking at the clone box on the top right and saw it said `hg@bitbucket`