# pip install from git repo branch/commit with submodules

Tags: git, pip

Similar to: [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch)

While you can install from a git repo branch/commit with the following syntax:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6
```

how does one specify pip to clone with submodules (--recursive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible and will not be implemented, even installation of packaging from git is not a fully supported instllation mechanism.

Shortly, clone it yourself, build the wheels, install the wheels.