# Upgrading the scikit-learn to a new version

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, conda

I want to upgrade my scikit-learn version to 0.18.dev0 which has the package for NeuralNetworl classifier and Regression. Can anyone give me detailed steps on how to do it on Windows. I want the steps to be very detailed.

What I tried was conda update scikit-learn, but what happens is it dosent go beyond "Fetching package Metadata..." and gets stuck there. Can anyone please help me with this. I am doing this on the command prompt.

Comment: why not try it yourself first and come back with a more specific question when you're stuck?

Comment: Sorry to bring the bad news: there is no binary-distribution of scikit-learn >=0.18 available, which means: you would need to compile it for yourself. Without some serios knowledge about preparing windows for the compilation of software from sources, this will be very hard. The good news: scikit-learns NeuralNetwork implementation is just a toy at the moment. If you want to use NNs, stick to much much more powerful software like keras and co. (which is also said by scikit-learns devs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to install from a specific git branch, like described in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/447599

Comment: pip is a python module and works just fine in batch and powershell (and cygwin and ubuntu-on-windows)

Comment: Are you serious? Okay... do ```pip install scipy``` please (but prepare your c++ compiler, fortran-compiler, atlas-distribution and co. first) :-)

Comment: not of numpy and scipy :3 but that also doesn't work great on Ubuntu (apt is better, or conda)

Comment: Yeah, scipy is the worst. But scikit-learn is a heavy-user of cython. So without a working C/C++ compiler (and all the other typical utils) it won't work!

Comment: Hi sascha, Can you please guide me how to prepare the c++ compiler, fortran compiler and atlas-distribution on windows? some detailed steps on it would be very helpful.