# Installing from Github using pip

Tags: github, installation, pip

I tried this `pip install`:

```
pip install https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py
```

I get the error 'SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax'.

Can I install from GitHub using `pip`?

Comment: People tell me this is the biggest error they've ever seen

Comment: This error is tremendous

Comment: Pip isn't made for installing directly from GitHub repos. It installs Python modules from the Python module catalog. (I've never used Python, but I know enough about it to know this is _the wrong way to do it_.)

Answer (score 2):

This package seems to be only for python 3.x. so just type the following command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py
```

The meaning of this command:

1. `python3 -m` is to specify the python version.
2. `pip install git+https:[URL]` is for git repos.
3. Note that point 2 can also be:`pip install git+git:[URL]` or `pip install --upgrade https:[URL]`.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is a command line utility outside of python.

Run `pip install https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py` on your terminal, not inside a python REPL.

Comment: where do i find the terminal

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: If you don't have pip yet, [look here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) fo instructions on how to install it.

After installing it, [open the command prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and run `pip install https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py`.

Comment: Also, check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch for some more info on cloning git repos with `pip`

Answer (score -1):

## This seems like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

You asked how to install python packages from GitHub using pip, whereas the real question is why bash commands don't work in python console.

### The difference

These two languages have different syntax, so you can't do that.
There are two simple solutions for this:

1. Use os module to run console commands:

```py
import os
os.system("pip install https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py")
```

This solution has a downside:
This is unnecessary complex.
The second solution solves it:

2. Use different tool.

Close python terminal/console/file you have open.
Open bash (or any other installed console) and then run

```bash
pip install https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py
```

Comment: I would love to know what's wrong with my answer.