# No module named graphite.settings

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, graphite

### Intro

I had a running instance of Graphite-Web 0.9.15, due to recent bug fixes and general slowness when loading data with Grafana I decided I should probably try and upgrade Graphite.

### What I did

I went on and `git cloned` all the repositories and then ran `python setup.py install` to the default location, the config files stayed where they were, I didn't merge.

When I tried to run the `uwsgi` app again I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'graphite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named graphite.settings
```

I'm not sure running `pip install` will do the trick since PyPI only has the 0.9.15 version.

### Conclusion

What I need is to find a way to make this `django` instance recognise the `graphite.settings` module.

I did manage to import `graphite.settings` module when runnning `python` externally at some point, now it's not working either.

### Edit: Config files

**/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/garphite.ini**

```
plugins=python
[uwsgi]
processes = 2
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
chdir = /opt/graphite/conf
module = wsgi:application
```

**/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini**

```
# User-made changes in this file will be silently lost, as it is silently
# rewrited with upgrade of uwsgi package.
#
# If you want to change default options of uWSGI daemon, then:
# * copy this file somewhere
# * add/remove/change options in copied file
# * edit /etc/default/uwsgi and change location of inherited configuration
#   file to path to copied file

[uwsgi]

# --------------------------
# About %(deb-confnamespace)
# --------------------------
#
# uWSGI init.d script passes environment variable UWSGI_DEB_CONFNAMESPACE to
# started uWSGI daemon, which is recognized as a (fake) option with name
# 'deb-confnamespace'.
#
# 'confnamespace' means 'configuration files namespace'. Namespace is the name
# of first directory in relative path to configuration file, but with stripped
# suffix 's-enabled'. "Relative path" means "path relative to /etc/uwsgi".
#
# Example: namespace of '/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/site.ini' is 'app'.

# ---------------------
# About %(deb-confname)
# ---------------------
#
# uWSGI init.d script passes environment variable UWSGI_DEB_CONFNAME to
# started uWSGI daemon, which is recognized as a (fake) option with name
# 'deb-confname'.
#
# 'confname' means 'configuration name', which is a filename without
# extension of the configuration file.
#
# Example: name of '/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/site.ini' is 'site'.

# try to autoload appropriate plugin if "unknown" option has been specified
autoload = true

# enable master process manager
master = true

# spawn 2 uWSGI worker processes
workers = 2

# automatically kill workers on master's death
no-orphans = true

# write master's pid in file /run/uwsgi/<confnamespace>/<confname>/pid
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/%(deb-confnamespace)/%(deb-confname)/pid

# bind to UNIX socket at /run/uwsgi/<confnamespace>/<confname>/socket
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(deb-confnamespace)/%(deb-confname)/socket

# set mode of created UNIX socket
chmod-socket = 660

# place timestamps into log
log-date = true

# user identifier of uWSGI processes
uid = www-data

# group identifier of uWSGI processes
gid = www-data
```

**Command:**

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /run/uwsgi/app/graphite/pid --exec /usr/bin/uwsgi -- --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/graphite.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/graphite.log
```

Running the internal command outside the `/etc/init.d/uwsgi` script yields:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/graphite.ini
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - option "module" found in plugin /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python_plugin.so
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (64bit) on [Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017] ***
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 06 July 2013 12:20:09
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - detected number of CPU cores: 4
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - current working directory: /root
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/%(deb-confnamespace)/%(deb-confname)/pid
Tue Feb  7 07:31:23 2017 - open("/run/uwsgi/%(deb-confnamespace)/%(deb-confname)/pid"): No such file or directory [utils.c line 4196]
```

And this is where the error might be coming from:
**/opt/graphite/conf/wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

try:
    from importlib import import_module
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'graphite.settings')  # noqa

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()

try:
    import whitenoise
except ImportError:
    whitenoise = False
else:
    # WhiteNoise < 2.0.1 does not support Python 2.6
    if sys.version_info[:2] < (2, 7):
        whitenoise_version = tuple(map(
                int, getattr(whitenoise, '__version__', '0').split('.')))
        if whitenoise_version < (2, 0, 1):
            whitenoise = False

if whitenoise:
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
    application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
    prefix = "/".join((settings.URL_PREFIX.strip('/'), 'static'))
    for directory in settings.STATICFILES_DIRS:
        application.add_files(directory, prefix=prefix)
    for app_path in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        module = import_module(app_path)
        directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(module.__file__), 'static')
        if os.path.isdir(directory):
            application.add_files(directory, prefix=prefix)
```

Anything else I can add?

#### Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint how do I solve this, or to be more specific: how do I make the `graphite.settings` accessible to the uwsgi?

Comment: show the code where you are trying to import it?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, it is not my code, I'll try and look for it but it might be complicated, there's a github repo.

Comment: @Alasdair, it's fairly complicated, there are 3 different components, I can try and find the code from the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cloning and installing yourself you could try installing the latest commit via pip as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/621690 (and further https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support)

```
pip install git+https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web.git
```

(add `@<hash/branch-spec>` to checkout a certain state)

Comment: And I posted this to show that there is a way to not fetch the pip version but to fetch from the (git) source directly which should be the same as cloning and building by hand.

Answer (score 1):

For the `wsgi.py` file to work, the outer `graphite` folder (the one that contains `manage.py`, not the inner one that contains `settings.py` has to be on the Python path.

It looks like uwsgi has a [`--pythonpath`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-django) option you can use, or you can add `sys.path.append('/path/to/graphite/)` in your wsgi file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same result by running below commands -

```
sudo graphite-manage migrate --run-syncdb
sudo graphite-manage migrate auth
```