# Can't install Python v3.6 packages on Windows 10 via pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, package

I recently installed python on my Windows 10 machine but I can't download packages via pip. I have 3.6.1 installed. PIP is version 9.0.1.

For example, this happens:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install parse-torrent-name
Collecting parse-torrent-name
  Using cached parse-torrent-name-1.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Kintesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uf2g9dii\parse-torrent
-name\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        description = f.read()
      File "c:\users\kintesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\encod
ings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 292:
character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Kintesh\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uf2g9dii\parse-torrent-name\
```

For the record, I've tried the following:

1. Installing pyCurl (Can't even remember why I did this now)
2. Tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and `easy_install -U setuptools`.

I got this working on pythonista on IOS easier than this - why does Windows have to be so difficult?!

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling Pip, or updating Pip

Comment: Pip is the most up to date version and yes, tried reinstalling too. Still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the package when installing on Windows, which is why you are getting the error. It is not a pip or Windows problem.

The author of the package has fixed the problem on GitHub (see the [commit](https://github.com/divijbindlish/parse-torrent-name/commit/26988d849f9436c3dda0932f6c60356da3ffbf69)), but not pushed the updated package onto PyPI, which is the default source for packages that are installed by pip and easy_install.

In the meantime, you can work around this by directly installing the latest package from GitHub with `pip install https://github.com/divijbindlish/parse-torrent-name/archive/master.zip`.

There are other ways to install packages from GitHub too, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/3800244). You can even download the zip manually, and install the zip with easy_install, if you want.