# Proper directory for third party library python3

Tags: python, package

I am working on a Python project
and have to use a third party library which is **not uploaded in pip**

Thus, I am going to put it in my project, Like this

`project----
    L mypackage 
       L somemodule.py
       L somemodule2.py
    L third-party-package
       L anymodule.py`

But, I am not sure this is good directory structure for python3

If I have to use many third-party-packages which are not uploaded in pip
Then I have to create many third party package folders like below

`project----
    L mypackage 
       L somemodule.py
       L somemodule2.py
    L third-party-package
       L anymodule.py
    L third-party-package2
       L anymodule2.py
    L third-party-package3
       L anymodule3.py`

May be the better structure likes below

`project----
    L mypackage 
       L somemodule.py
       L somemodule2.py
    L lib
       L third-party-package
          L anymodule.py
       L third-party-package2
          L anymodule2.py
       L third-party-package3
          L anymodule3.py`

But in this case,
It will create import errors inside `third-party-pacakge`
Since the root package is now `lib`

So what is the good structure? 
For this kind of case???

Comment: Why not use a virtualenv and install the package with `pip`?

Comment: @Grimmy The library cannot be downloaded through pip.
The library I am using now, is just uploaded in git repo and that's all

Comment: Of course you can install install it with pip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Comment: I got it Grimmy! thanks!

Comment: You can also set up a private pip repository fairly quick using `devpi`. Then you can build wheels of your private projects instead if source distributions. A lot faster to install.

Comment: Great! thanks Grimmy again :)