# Why does pybrain 0.3.1 install instead of 0.3.3?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble installing the proper version of PyBrain. This is a problem.

```
(rnine) ronaldo@ronaldo-laptop:~$ pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip
Collecting https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip
     \ 1.5MB 1.4MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./.conda/envs/rnine/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from PyBrain==0.3.1)
Installing collected packages: PyBrain
  Running setup.py install for PyBrain ... done
Successfully installed PyBrain-0.3.1
```

As you can see, it keeps installing PyBrain 0.3.1 even though I'm pulling in the 0.3.3 folder. Why is this happening and how can I fix this.

Comment: So you tried ```pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip --upgrade```? Sidenote: pybrain is [dead](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/commits/master).

Comment: What does the --upgrade flag do? And it didn't work.

Comment: Sraw seems to be right. As an alternative, you can use pip to install from the master-branch [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) (if you trust the devs on how stable this branch is; it's newer than the release for sure), where setup.py is using 0.3.3. Not sure if you would need ```--upgrade```.

Answer (score 1):

Download this package and see its `setup.py`, you will see `version="0.3.1"`, so this is a bug made by author.

You have nothing to do with it except for modifying source code by yourself.