# How can I specify a custom Git branch in my Pipfile?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv, pipenv

It is possible to specify in `Pipfile` packages from custom Git repository.
But I cannot find comprehensive documentation on how to specify the concrete branch or a commit to be used for installation.

Is there a complete reference on how to use Git URLs for python packages in the `Pipfile` that are supported by the [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) for specifying custom branches, versions, or commits?

It would be really nice to have it with equivalent `pipenv` command line arguments.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is [some documentation](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/basics.rst#-a-note-about-vcs-dependencies) on the GitHub repo for pipenv:

> You can install packages with pipenv from git and other version
> control systems using URLs formatted according to the following rule:
>
> ```
> <vcs_type>+<scheme>://<location>/<user_or_organization>/<repository>@<branch_or_tag>#egg=<package_name>
> ```

So, for example:

```ini
[packages]
requests = {git = "https://github.com/requests/requests.git", editable = true, ref = "v2.20.1"}
```

You can generate a Pipfile using the command line. The Pipfile above was generated with:

```bash
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/requests/requests.git@v2.20.1#egg=requests
```

The documentation for pip [goes into more detail](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/).

Comment: I was successfully installing our packages from GIT referring to this documentation while I have totally forgotten about this question of mine asked before such information was available. The first reference of the [VCS](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/commit/bcad23874f60469a6e4faab41c795550f024b195) committed on Sep 20, 2017, did not mention the possibility of specifying branches until [this](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/commit/a3162945be79182d0a4b4a7c140970dc340788fb) edit was committed on Aug 12, 2018. Maybe this answer a good candidate for a community wiki?

Comment: This worked for me, but note that the "egg" needs to be the *original project name,* not some other name you define in the misguided attempt to avoid a naming conflict. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### `pip` package archives

In addition to [Alex's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783019/241211), you can also use `pip`'s "archive" format on [a zipped copy of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/241211). Several code hosts automatically provide zip files at predictable URLs.

### Why would I do this?

The VCS installation works perfectly fine. This alternative is convenient if the machine you're installing on does not have Git, like [a "slim" container image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1&name=slim). Previous reports suggested that this method was faster than Git, but they seem comparable now.

### Examples

Replace the tokens with the values you want in the code samples below.

| Field | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `<package>` | The name of the package. ([Match the package's name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783019/241211#comment132232460_53783019) from its `setup.py`!) |
| `<user>` | The repository owner |
| `<repo>` | The repository name |
| `<refname>` | Branch, tag, or commit SHA. Bitbucket can also use `default` for the default branch. |

#### `Pipfile`

```ini
[packages]
<package> = {file = "https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<refname>.zip"}
<package> = {file = "https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/get/<refname>.zip"}
<package> = {file = "https://codeberg.org/<user>/<repo>/archive/<refname>.zip"}
<package> = {file = "https://gitlab.com/<user>/<repo>/-/archive/<refname>/<repo>-<refname>.zip"}
```

#### CLI installation

```bash
pipenv install https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<refname>.zip
pipenv install https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/get/<refname>.zip
pipenv install https://codeberg.org/<user>/<repo>/archive/<refname>.zip
pipenv install https://gitlab.com/<user>/<repo>/-/archive/<refname>/<repo>-<refname>.zip
```

### Warning

There are reports from [2017](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/772#issuecomment-333110879) and [2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/241211#comment83088617_24811490) that unlike `pip`, *`pipenv` **will not** recursively install dependencies* from zips. Dependencies are working fine for me, though. [This commit](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/commit/683df2f8ad73e53e9e50364a9cfeb7493a7f1552) from September 2018 is my best guess for when things changed, but if you know otherwise, please comment or edit.