# How do I reference a local git branch in Pipfile?

Tags: python, git, pipenv

Having 2 different repositories in local, I want to reference the feature branch of the repository 2 form the Pipfile of the repository 1.

How is it donde? I have this line in the Pipfile of repository 1 but it fails when generating the lock file.

```
repository2 = {editable = true, extras = ["dev"], path = "/Users/name.surname/Projects/repository2", branch = "feature/my_branch"}
```

Comment: Might just be a typo; `path = /Users/...` (you are missing the leading `/` in the path name).

Comment: Hi @chepner, yes there was a typo in the path.
Sadly the error remains after fixing that.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can reference a branch from a path. A path is a path to source code, `pipenv` knows nothing about branches in the source code. So either you checkout the branch yourself or you tell to `pipenv` that the path is actually a repository so that `pipenv` clones it and checks out the branch:

```
repository2 = {editable = true, extras = ["dev"], git = "file:///Users/name.surname/Projects/repository2", ref = "feature/my_branch"}
```

In command line:

```bash
pipenv install git+file:///Users/name.surname/Projects/repository2@feature/my_branch
```

See another example at [How can I specify a custom Git branch in my Pipfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47617552/7976758)

Comment: This is what happened. Thanks so much for for your response :)