# Install dicompyler for python using conda or pip

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda, pydicom

I am trying to install dicompyler to read DICOM-RT plan files through conda, but getting a 'PackageNotFoundError'.

The package is on Github at https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core.  When downloading and install the tar using

```
pip install [directory\filename]
```

I get 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in [directory]'.

Is there a way to install either through conda or from the tar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to install the packages from the github, and it seems succeeded. Below is my step:

1:Clone the code:

```
git clone https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core.git
```

2:Install from the source:

```
cd dicompyler-core
sudo python3.6 setup.py install
```

3:Result:

```
..........
Using /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for dicompyler-core==0.5.3


Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dicompylercore
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't run the git clone command (due a firewall my work network?), but was able to download a .zip from https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core.git and install using "python setup.py install".  This was on windows, btw: "sudo" doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, sudo is Linux command to use superuser  privilege. On windows, just run "python setup.py install" will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Anaconda in your project you need to create its environment in the directory of your project:

```
conda create --name env python=3
```

Then activate it:

```
source activate env
```

Then download the archive from the github if you're trying to install the package from archive. Unpack the archive and then enter the unpacked directory and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then it will successfully install the required package dicompyler.

Hope this helps.