# Error installing django-nvd3

Tags: python, django, pip, python-nvd3

I have the following error when executing the following command `pip3 install django-nvd3`

```
Collecting django-nvd3
  Using cached django-nvd3-0.9.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/rs/30thcgbd2334t5kfx1n3fj5w0000gn/T/pip-build-g97vw973/django-nvd3/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        readme = readme_file.read()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2070: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rs/30thcgbd2334t5kfx1n3fj5w0000gn/T/pip-build-g97vw973/django-nvd3/
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are hitting [this issue](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/issues/95). It looks as if it [has been fixed](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/commit/b10f30661ffd47317b78c03d4cb542d638cc64e8), but there hasn't been a release since then.

You could try installing the master branch. This might be a good idea anyway, since [0.9.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nvd3/0.9.7) was released in 2015.

Alternatively, or you could try setting `LANG`, as suggested in this [similar issue](https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify/issues/16) for a different project.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF8 pip3 install django-nvd3
```

Comment: How can I install it on pip3 downloading the master branch?

Comment: See [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Answer (score 0):

Check if setuptools is properly installed:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```