# Error while calling function in Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am trying to run the repository of [IqoptionAppi](https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi)

While I am trying to run the command: `api.getcandles(1,60,25)`
the following error occured:

```
api.getcandles(1,60,25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I have seen the function and is something like this:

```
from iqoptionapi.ws.chanels.base import Base


class GetCandles(Base):
    """Class for IQ option candles websocket chanel."""
    # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods

    name = "candles"

    def __call__(self, active_id, duration, amount):
        """Method to send message to candles websocket chanel.

        :param active_id: The active/asset identifier.
        :param duration: The candle duration (timeframe for the candles).
        :param amount: The number of candles you want to have
        """
        data = {"active_id": active_id,
                "duration": duration,
                "chunk_size": 25,
                "from": self.api.timesync.server_timestamp - (duration * amount),
                "till": self.api.timesync.server_timestamp}

        self.send_websocket_request(self.name, data)
```

The repository says it works in `Python 2.7` but I tried installing it on `Python 3.5`, it still worked except the above issue. Guide me where exactly I missed.

Comment: I believe you are providing self as a first argument. When calling a class member method, python does it for you.

Comment: @Sianur But I am not using it while calling the function you can see it in my example.

Comment: Post the lines where you create the api object

Comment: @miindlek ok see this:  `api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "name@email.com", "Passwordhidden")`, This is the way I have create the object.

Comment: well, i've installed it locally and there are only 2 parameters (except `self`): `active_id`, `duration`

Comment: seems that amount defaults to `2`

Comment: where have you taken this class definition from?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I have share link on the repository in the question please check the first line of question.

Comment: my local version is [0.5](https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi/blob/0.5/iqoptionapi/ws/chanels/candles.py) and it seems to be [the latest on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/iqoptionapi/0.5/#history)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov May be. I do not know the version let me check it out

Comment: @AzatIbrakov exactly the same version. `Version: 0.5`. Please note I am using python 3.5 ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that [*iqoptionapi/ws/chanels/candles.py*](https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi/tree/0.5/iqoptionapi/ws/chanels/candles.py) module from [latest **PyPI** version](https://pypi.org/project/iqoptionapi/0.5/) differs from [**Github**'s `master` branch version](https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi/blob/master/iqoptionapi/ws/chanels/candles.py) and there is no `amount` parameter (it seems to be equal to `2`).

In `master` branch:

```
def __call__(self, active_id, duration, amount):
    ...
    "from": self.api.timesync.server_timestamp - (duration * amount),
    ...
```

In `0.5` version:

```
def __call__(self, active_id, duration):
    ...
    "from": self.api.timesync.server_timestamp - (duration * 2),
    ...
```

So we can ignore this parameter (do not pass it at all and use default value `2`) or [install `master` branch version using `git`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) like

```
> pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi.git@master
```

Here we are using `--upgrade` flag since version didn't change so we force to reinstall package.

Or another option: you can ask repo owner to release new version and publish it on **PyPI**.

Comment: Afer updating, I am getting the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'`