# pip install wheel version from private github repo

Tags: python, git, github, python-wheel

I've packaged my private repo into a wheel. There are different versions of the wheel. Is it possible to install a specific wheel version of the repo using pip from the command line and via the requirements.txt file? This feature [isn't mentioned in the pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) from what I can tell.

I can install a pip package from a private repository with no problem, using a Github token.

`pip install git+https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/[username]/[reponame].git`

I can also install a private pip package with a specific commit:

`pip install git+https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/[username]/[reponame].git@[commit_sha]`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/1176573) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46666538/1176573).

Answer (score 1):

According to current docs, installing wheels (with or without pinned version) [from VCS](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/vcs-support/) is currently not supported by pip, and maybe it never will.

I suspect the reason is that a wheel is basically a "compiled artifact", so you wouldn't usually find those committed into a git repository, e.g. all the examples from the [VCS page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/vcs-support/) show examples that would install that dependency from source and build it locally.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to install a specific wheel, you give pip the path or URL for that wheel:

```
pip install https://example.com/url/of/wheel.whl
```

Comment: Can you please specify the url format if the wheel.whl locates in the "dist" folder of a repo branch?

Comment: @Chenlu: If you want to install from a local file, simply give the path to the file: `pip install /path/to/wheel.whl`

Comment: @rjurney: This Q&A is for the case where you have a built wheel file that you want to install with pip.  If you have a git repo but no wheel file, this does not apply to you.

Comment: @jwodder I see, my mistake.