# Download Python library from Github with Anaconda

Tags: python, github

I am looking to download a Python library (specifically [this one](https://github.com/rbarton65/espnff)) from GitHub.

I had already downloaded it using `pip install espnff` but it appears changes have been made to it and the only way to get the updated version is through GitHub. I should also mention that I use Python with the Anaconda distribution, if that affects anything.

How do I download and update what I already have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make sure that `pip` actually uses you anaconda python distribution, and not e.g. the one that comes as default on your OS. You can use `which pip` to do that.

After that, it is as easy as

```
pip install espnff --upgrade
```

If the latest changes have not yet been made available on `pip`, you could also try to install it manually from source. Taken from the repository you linked:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbarton65/espnff

cd espnff

python setup.py install
```

To make sure that you're installing the latest version available, you should use `git pull` to fetch and merge the latest changes before installing.

On some occasions, you might also have to delete the existing `build` directory first, or use

```
python setup.py build --force
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I've got `error: option --upgrade not recognized` when running the last line, would it work without the "--upgrade" part?

Comment: My bad, there's no such option for installing from source.