# Heroku Failed Push: Distribution version mismatch with Anaconda-Client

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, conda, heroku-cli

I created a twitter bot in python/jupyter notebook that I'm now trying to launch on Heroku. You can see it here: https://github.com/ivorygrant/TwitterAnalyzer

Anyway, I'm having a really tough time trying to figure this out. I've tried following several pages but I'm just not getting it. When I try to push the app, I get an error saying

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.14
```

According to PyPI the latest version according to pip is 1.2.2 but for some reason I have a higher version. One suggestion was to remove the version in the requirements.txt, that didn't work. I then changed it to 1.2.2 but no luck. From what I understand the error lies in the usage of conda vs pip? When I ran the freeze requirements, it automatically added anaconda-client. I even tried removing that requirement, but then I get another error that another distribution doesn't match, this time clyent.

If someone can walk me through or point me in the right direction, the basic idea or steps I need to take and I will figure it out! I think the solution is "if no match, point to this source (conda) and check here" or get rid of conda but that might mess more things up? help!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-client/files, the available version for anaconda-client is `1.7.2`, while https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/ lists `1.2.2` & non updated homepage http://github.com/Anaconda-client/anaconda-client (instead of their current repo https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client)

My suggestion is to use pip to install the stable version (or whichever version you're after) [from github .git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/10254804) instead of pypi.

Comment: pip install git+https://github.com/Anaconda-Server/anaconda-client 

It didn't work for me. I tried the other suggestions on the page (pip and conda install) still nothing.

Comment: @IvoryGrant `pip -v install git+https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client.git` for master version, or if you _really_ need 1.6.x use the one in https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client/tree/1.6.x

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :(

FYI I ran a bunch of commands and eventually updated to anaconda-client 1.7.2 and my requirements.txt file reflects this. I recreated the requirements.txt file, re-installed the packages in requirements.txt, and still nothing. I will try exiting my conda environment and running that line you posted again, maybe the conda environment is stopping it from being updated?

Comment: @IvoryGrant according to the doc, you can use conda to install anaconda-client http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/getting-started/#cloud-install-client. try that first, `conda install anaconda-client`. It does sounds like virtual env or path related.

Comment: tried that suggestion, same error. Then I thought to just remove that line and any subsequent package that gives me an error and try to work backwards from there (i.e. do I really need this package). But then I thought, my code only has a few dependencies, namely tweepy, numpy, matplotlib.pyplot, pandas, so isn't that all i need in the requirements? I'm not sure what generates the requirements, if it's just some blanket file that installs every single package in my environment, or actually knows what it needs to work. This my first time pushing to heroku btw

Comment: well if you have a python installed that didn't come from anaconda, you can certainly try make a virtual environment, activate it & install those modules with pip so you can run your app there.