# Heroku pip install failing to install billy-api

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, heroku

Im trying to install a newer version of the bitly-api via GitHub on my heroku server as we have been having issues going from 2.7.15 to 3.6.6 so I added the git+git:https://URLOFGIT.GIT and I seem to be getting the below error. What does it mean?

Do I need to force it to use pip3?

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Found python-2.7.15, removing
-----> Installing python-3.6.6
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+git:https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python.git (from -r /tmp/build_c254deea58fb0d0ccb947f1819f45b29/requirements.txt (line 25))
         Cloning git:///https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python.git to /tmp/pip-tibxul79-build
       fatal: unable to connect to :
       : Name or service not known

       Command "git clone -q git:///https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python.git /tmp/pip-tibxul79-build" failed with error code 128 in None
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct way of providing GitHub URL in requirements.txt
`https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python/archive/v0.3.zip`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/3007402 (See the last line)

Comment: I then get an error like this 

`Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-hn9iz7hb-unpack/bitly-api-python.git (downloaded from /tmp/pip-uu8dd6k5-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
remote:        Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-uu8dd6k5-build
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.`