# Updating gspread to get duplicate_sheet

Tags: gspread

How do I update `gspread` to get the `sheet.duplicate_sheet` method?  I need to duplicate a sheet and can't seem to get the module updated to the latest version (3.1.0).

Comment: How have you tried updating it? Newest version on PyPI is [3.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/)

Comment: The github repo has documentation that refers to 3.1.0 which has "duplicate_sheet".  Just wondering how I can get that version, I dont see any installation notes for grabbing the code from github and installing.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Can you post what you already did?  I feel like the answer provided below is something you may have already done.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue on Google Colab. Perhaps this answer helps others like me.

The pre-installed package on Colab is currently 3.0.1, so you need to manually force an upgrade to get eg duplicate_sheet working.

```
!pip install gspread --upgrade
import gspread
```

If you've already imported the pre-installed version, you need to restart the runtime - you will be prompted to do that once you run the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.1.0 is now available on PyPI. You can upgrade with:

```
pip install --upgrade gspread
```

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate!

According to the OP, the answer is found at [this duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch).

### Direct quote of the answer by Falsetru and Das-G:

> Prepend the url prefix git+ (See VCS Support):
>
> `pip install
>   git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6`
>
> And specify the branch name *without* the leading `/`.