# Is it possible to execute a bash script to download non-python dependencies on `pip install my-package`

Tags: python, bash, dependencies, wget, pypi

I have a python package `my-package` that depends on a binary `binary.exe` but this binary is too big to be uploaded to pypi. Therefore I want to execute a bash script when the user does `pip install ...` that will `wget` the binary from my github and place it in their `site-packages/my-package` folder. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: pip can install stuff directly from github. Perhaps this could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could follow is adding the code to fetch the binary in your package itself, so that any time it gets imported, it first downloads the binary. You can do this using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), or you can simply run your wget command using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, though the requests approach is more robust.

Comment: *any time it gets imported, it first downloads the binary* Will not work because: 1) the network could be down when the script is ran; 2) the user who runs the script may not have write access to the installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. pip lags far behind real package namers like deb/rpm; pip-installable packages are rather primitive ones, they don't have pre/post-(un)install scripts.

You have to create your own installer using PyInstaller, py2exe, py2app or cx_Freeze. Or said deb/rpm — there are plugins for setuptools to generate debs and rpms.