# Can a specific file from a specific github repo tree be installed with pip?

Tags: github, pip, installation

I need to install [tensorflow_backend.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e3a2f7d29f2f1c21ecc978bd0038b1d1330d33c2/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py) from a specific tree in keras, ideally without updating the other keras files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20101834/11313663) shows how to install a specific repo branch, but how can the same be done for this single file in a tree?

Comment: Probably not. Even if this is possible it's not a good idea to mix and match files from different revisions. Why don't you want to update the whole library?

Comment: @Chris I am experiencing the issue detailed [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10648) and trying to implement the proposed solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `pip` installs **Python packages**. You need a different tool to download just one file. For a remote git repository `git archive` is a good tool. For a remote web interface use `curl` or `wget`.