# Install DRF 3.12 Alpha

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use a pre-release version of Django Rest Framework (DRF) in order to take advantage of the new JSONField feature. There doesn't appear to be a version to  "pip install" for alpha 3.12. What is the appropriate way to install the alpha version into my env?

Comment: there is no 3.12 alpha tag

Comment: How can I install the latest 3.12 pre-release?

Answer (score 0):

You can install directly master branch of [drf](http://%20https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework) ([related question](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) )

You can see which features are already merged or if you need other branch for particular feature ( [drf 3.12 release milestone](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/milestone/76) )

```
pip install git@github.com:encode/django-rest-framework.git
```

Comment: This seems like it is the way to go. I had to add "git+" to make it work, and in my case I went with the http. "pip install git+https://github.com:encode/django-rest-framework.git". It says it is 3.11. Is it 3.11 with all of the latest changes on top of it? Or do I need to do something to get the correct tag or branch for 3.12?

Comment: @Greg as in answer you should tag master branch

Comment: Thanks for the help!