# Merging contributor PR into Tweepy installation

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I am trying to upload videos using the Tweepy Python library, but the official version doesn't currently support it.

That said, there is a side branch created by a contributor that has added the functionality. The branch is ready for merging with the main branch, but there's no ETA. I need to implement this as soon as possible.

How can I merge this PR into my current Tweepy installation (via `pip`) so I can use this function?

This is the PR in question: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/929

Comment: Something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/1349663

Answer (score 0):

Use pip's Git installation feature. `pip install git+https://github.com/conversocial/tweepy.git@video_upload2`

Comment: Would this replace Tweepy as my primary installation? Would I need to invoke this library differently in my application? Also how would I undo this installation when the official Tweepy includes this functionality?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage this will replace your normal installation, you can do `pip install --upgrade --force tweepy` to revert back to the main installation.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!