# (Djoser) Weird activation email when I update the user fields

Tags: python, django, djoser

Every time when I try to **update** my user with the **PATCH** method to the ***/users/me/*** endpoint, an activation email is always sent. The user is already active in the system... so I don't know what is happening.

SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL is True, but I understand that the email will be sent only after:
creating an account
or updating their email (I'm not updating the email)

```
DJOSER = {
    ....
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'auth/users/activation/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    ....
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/546#issuecomment-772146085

Comment: I made a [pull request](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/pull/638#event-5845913084) and was merged with master code in djoser. This will fix the issue with `patch` or `put` requests to `/auth/users/me/` endpoint and send activation email only when `email` is updated and is not the same as the previous email.

Comment: @AlirezaAsadi can you please help me. I have the same issue and Im not sure how to add this code into my serializers. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: @MarkMcKeon You can check `Files changed` part in the pull request and make the same changes in your project **OR** you can directly install `djoser` from its master branch to get the latest version (which has activation email fixed). Here is a question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Comment: @AlirezaAsadi Thanks for your prompt reply. I managed to work it out last night!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. This is due to the `djoser.views.UserViewSet.perform_update` method.

```
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
    super().perform_update(serializer)
    user = serializer.instance
    #should we send activation email after update?
    if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
        context = {"user": user}
        to = [get_user_email(user)]
        settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
```

As you can see, even if you use email as a login field, you keep getting email confirmation if you update any field. This is not the right thing to do. This should be done only if the email has changed.

In your case the update part should be omitted:

```
#user = serializer.instance
#should we send activation email after update?    
#if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
        #context = {"user": user}
        #to = [get_user_email(user)]
        #settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
```

Comment: Why did you comment out all the code?