# Failing to install packages from GitHub with pip

Tags: python, git, pip

I'm trying to download an application from Github that runs on python. However, I am a complete newbie and falling at the first hurdle. The first step to install says

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/abey79/vsketch#egg=vsketch
$ pip install git+https://github.com/marceloprates/prettymaps.git
```

however when I try this is wont recognise this all I get is errors. Am I missing a step or typing this in the wrong place?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Please, edit your question to include all relevant information - what does "wont recognise" means, what errors do you get?

Comment: I think you got confused between `git clone` and `pip install`.

Comment: @AlbinPaul, one can isntall from GitHub, no need to clone first, unless they want. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20101834/4046632

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git clone https://github.com/abey79/vsketch#egg=vsketch
```

Then just run the `setup.py` from that directory, or the `app.py` whatever the startup file is. It should written somewhere in the readme file (e.g. `README.md`) or somewhere else.

You start it as...

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

...when you are in the directory.