# How to install specific github repo branch?

Tags: github, installation, branch, git-branch

I am trying to install a very recent [branch](https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/pull/2214) of a github repo into my google colab editor. I guess I haven't yet figured out the correct syntax, despite trying out different [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) on StackOverflow. What I have tried so far is

```
pip install git+https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/pull/2214
pip install git+https://github.com/weaverba137/astroquery/tree/sdss-spectra-url
```

but they both result in error messages. What is the correct way to download the branch? Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out on my own how to download the correct version/branch/patch. To do this follow the link to the branch that I posted in the question. Then click in the top to the link pointing to the origin of the branch:

[image]

Then in the new page click on the green "Code" button with a drop down and from there copy the address of this repo/branch/pull/patch/whatever it is called:

[image]

And eventually do with this copied address

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/weaverba137/astroquery.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked in my colab:

```
pip install https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/archive/main.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to install the main branch, but the one I have put a link to. Do you know how I can download it?