# Pip3 patch package in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I have the unfortunate situation that I need to patch a package inside my virtualenv because of version conflict requirements that prohibit upgrading a package with a bug inside it.

Is there any way of providing patch files to pip when installing requirements from a .txt file?
I could not find anything searching for "pip venv provide patches" and so on.
I guess the solution would be to wrap it inside a bash script, but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way of providing patch files to pip when installing requirements from a .txt file?

No, there is not. [`pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/) does not support this.

One alternative would be to [point pip to a patched version of the package](https://groups.google.com/g/python-virtualenv/c/kjmXrWXMcS4), e.g. at a [git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch). The linked Google thread also suggests checking out [Paver](https://github.com/paver/paver).