# should I upload/add another repository to my new project repository? If so, how to avoid git wanting to add this?

Tags: git, repository, repository-design

My current project/repository `repoA` depends on a different self-made repository `repoB` . This `repoB` contains some very general functions such that I can be used by other projects as well. That is the reason why I put these general functions in a different repository. So after cloning this `repoB` with git in `repoA`, my directory setup looks as following,

```
- repoA
---- repoB
```

When running the command `git status` inside `~/repoA`, it warns me that I have untracked files which makes sense as I just have cloned this new repository.

My question is: should I add/commit this other repository `repoB` to `repoA` What is the best practice with using multiple repositories? My gut feeling says that having the code of `repoB` existing twice (because it exists inside `repoA` as well) is unnecessary .

In the case that I do not want to add this `repoB` to `repoA`; is `.gitignore` the way to go therefore?

EDIT:
extra context, `repoB` contains python code representing dynamics and calculating commands for a robot and `repoA` contains (python) code to create a ROS package

Comment: Use a dependency manager for the specific language/domain. Don't try and force git to support that role.

Comment: Also for my own custom written “packages”?

Comment: Yes. Tools like npm (for JS) specifically support this.

Comment: Did you try to use git submodule? https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you for the suggestion; do you have any python specific suggestions?

Comment: @EduardoSilva, thank you for the suggestion; I will take a look at it. However, I do think that my problem/question is not so specific that it needs a whole extra software step. Using other repositories in new project happens all the time I would guess? I'm I approaching this problem from a incorrect perspective?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch you can install packages using pip directly from a git repo

Comment: @HerChip, I think that you are trying share code using different repos, submodules is the best solution. You could try use a clone repo inside you main repo but I thnk is hard to keep is up-to-date. Submodule works exactly way you are looking for.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that are packages from pypi, I'm talking about my own custom packages

Comment: @HerChip the link I gave shows installing a custom package using pip.