# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lispy

Tags: python, pip

I read book, I try practice these code snippet

```py
>>> from lis import parse
>>> parse('1.5')
1.5
```

Then I follow guide at https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy#getting-started . My PC is Windows 11 Pro x64.

```
C:\Users\donhu>python -V
Python 3.10.4

C:\Users\donhu>pip -V
pip 22.0.4 from C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

C:\Users\donhu>pip install lispy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lispy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lispy

C:\Users\donhu>
```

[image]

I also try install with Anaconda, but not success.

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

lispy is not a library in pip downloadable library. Instead, install lispy from the github repo. Here is a [Link to post explaining how install directly from github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Comment: Please revise your answer. You said near true. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/165529265-1f2c9611-67a3-49a3-b147-fa441c8daa33.png

Comment: I see http://norvig.com/lispy.html and http://norvig.com/lis.py Please help me a working solution. This is code snippet I need practice https://github1s.com/donhuvy/example-code-2e/blob/HEAD/02-array-seq/lispy/py3.9/examples_test.py

Comment: @DaoMinhThu this is not version to install - but simply download `lis.py` and put in folder in which you run your code.

Comment: @DaoMinhThu I can install this [lispy](https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy) using `pip install git+https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy` (with `git+` before `https`) but this install program `lispy` which I can run in console and it waits for lisp commands (interactive mode). Eventually I can `import lispy` but this is not original `lis.py` but modification and it doesn't have `parse()` but `lispy.runtime.parse()`

Answer (score 1):

It seems Norvig's [lispy](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) is not module for installing but you have to download [lis.py](http://norvig.com/lis.py) and put in folder with your code - or you would have to manually put it in folder with other modules.

---

As for github repo [adamhaney/lispy](https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy): on Linux I can install it using `git+` before `https`

```
pip install git+https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy
```

But this is not original `lis.py` but some modification and it needs

```
import lispy

parsed = lispy.runtime.parse('(define pi 3.141592653589793)')
result = lispy.runtime.eval(parsed)

parsed = lispy.runtime.parse('(define r 10)')
result = lispy.runtime.eval(parsed)

parsed = lispy.runtime.parse('(* pi (* r r))')
result = lispy.runtime.eval(parsed)

print(result)
```

or more useful

```
import lispy

def cmd(text):
    parsed = lispy.runtime.parse(text)
    result = lispy.runtime.eval(parsed)
    if result:
        print(result)

# --- main ---

cmd('(define pi 3.141592653589793)')
cmd('(define r 10)')
cmd('(* pi (* r r))')
```

or using interactive mode which displays prompt `lispy>`

```
import lispy

lispy.runtime.Runtime().repl()
```

---

**BTW:** repo [adamhaney/lispy](https://github.com/adamhaney/lispy) is 10 years old (last update on 6 Jul 2013)
and maybe this is problem. Maybe this `lispy` was removed from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/) and now you can't install it with `pip`

---

**EDIT:**

See also main page [norvig.com](http://norvig.com/) - there is link to ["NEW" List of Jupyter/Ipython notebooks](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes#pytudes-index-of-jupyter-ipython-notebooks) with the newest materials (even from 2022)