# uwsgi PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, uwsgi, bottle

I have uwsgi==2.0.20 and python[CPython 3.10.4]. And I can't execute the following code:

```
uwsgi.cache_get(key, 'mycache')
```

Error:

```
PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats.
```

Is there any way to fix this for myself by setting PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN to a Dockerfile or something?
Because in the latest version of uwsgi it is not fixed yet, as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [merged pull request](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/2363), but the new version containing that fix isn't released yet. What we ended up doing in our company is using the source code from the development branch. You can install it [from GitHub using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch). Though it isn't the best idea to have a dependency from a development version of a package.

Comment: thank you, you're right, at the moment the fixes have not yet been released, I was also given an answer in the GitHub from the developers that the fix is in the branch `uwsgi-2.0`
https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2440#issuecomment-1147195561

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to use Redis directly, I decided to use Redis