# error when I try to import tflearn : cannot import name 'is_sequence' from 'tensorflow.python.util.nest'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, import, jupyter-notebook, tflearn

I already have `tflearn` installed and I get the following error when I try to import it:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sequence' from 'tensorflow.python.util.nest' (C:\Users\fsafi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py)
```

I tried the following:

```
import tflearn
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101940/14872121):
You can solve the issue by running:

```
pip uninstall tflearn
pip install git+https://github.com/MihaMarkic/tflearn.git@fix/is_sequence_missing
```

Comment: @AIASAD WAIL : Thank you. That was quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered exactly the same issue when setting up a new tf environment. I believe it is because tflearn==0.5.0 which is too old and cannot work with latest tensorflow=2.13.0.

I have to fall back tensorflow to older version such as 2.12.0 to make it works.

There is also a PR on tflearn to fix this problem but it is still work in progress:
https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/1173/commits

Basically *is_sequence(args)* will be replaced with *is_sequence_or_composite(args)*.

```
from tensorflow.python.util.nest import is_sequence_or_composite
```

```
if args is None or (is_sequence_or_composite(args) and not args):
 raise ValueError("`args` must be specified")
if not is_sequence_or_composite(args):
 args = [args]
```

Besides, the Pillow-10.0 gave the same issue which can be fixed by replacing it with Pillow-9.5 or you can replace the ANTIALIAS with LANCZOS by the utils.py file like we did for the reccurent.py file of tflearn library.

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==9.5.0
```

I just uploaded the previous version of PIL and it totally works right now.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue! See, if you don't want to go back to old Tensorflow versions try these:

1. Fork the Tflearn repo https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn
2. See the updates in one the pull requests (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/1173) of this repo
3. Make these changes in your forked repo
4. The uninstall Tflearn and then reinstall tflearn from your forked repo

- Just do pip install `git+https://github.com/<your_github_user_name>/<forked_repo_name>.git`