# pandas_csv_sniffer installation fails using either conda, pip, or setup.py

Tags: python, pandas, conda, jupyter-lab, read-csv

I am having difficulty installing the [pandas_csv_sniffer](https://github.com/jdfekete/pandas_csv_sniffer) Python package with the current versions of pandas, Python, conda, and pip.

(This package provides a helpful jupyter notebook GUI for finding good parameters to the pandas.csv_read function.)

A conda package would be the most robust, but I don't know how to rebuild and distribute this as a standard conda package. I even tried using the setup.py file, which is a deprecated method.

The setup.cfg and pyproject.toml files were not helpful to figure out package dependencies.

I searched and could not find any questions or answers related this package on Stack Overflow. What is the best way to install this?

I am using the following relevant package versions:

- Python v3.11
- pandas v2.1.2

WHAT I TRIED:
I tried several ways to install this package:

1. `conda install -c conda-forge pandas_csv_sniffer` ---> FAILED
   This fails with a message "package not available in conda channels", so this means there is no condda package.
2. `pip install pandas_csv_sniffer` ---> FAILED

```
(base) C:\Users\hilar>pip install pandas_csv_sniffer
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas_csv_sniffer (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas_csv_sniffer
```

3. `python setup.py install`: The setup.py installation method *seemed* to work, but then when I try to import it the package cannot be found.

```
(pandas_tools2) C:\Users\hilar\Desktop\00_PythonWIP\pandas_csv_sniffer>python
Python 3.11.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct 3 2023, 10:29:11) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  
import pandas_csv_sniffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_csv_sniffer'
```

---

Here is a snapshot of the current environment, created specifically to try to install this package (conda and pip install commands failed, then "python setup.py install" was used).

```
(pandas_tools2) C:\Users\hilar\Desktop\00_PythonWIP\pandas_csv_sniffer>pip list

DEPRECATION: Loading egg at c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pandas_tools2\lib\site-packages\csv_sniffer_jdfekete-0.1-py3.11.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at pypa/pip#12330
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pandas_tools2\lib\site-packages\fsspec-2023.10.0-py3.11.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at pypa/pip#12330
```

Package version: [full list of packages in my environment](https://github.com/jdfekete/pandas_csv_sniffer/issues/11)

Comment: Is there a pypi package called "pandas_csv_sniffer". It looks like that is just a standalone thing. Perhaps this might help [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Comment: your links to GItHub shows image with `Jupyter` and `import csv_sniffer`, but you use `import pandas_csv_sniffer`. It seems you use wrong name (after `python setup.py install`)

Answer (score 1):

Repo on `GitHub` has name `pandas_csv_sniffer` but Python module has name `csv_sniffer`.

See image with `Jupyter` on `GitHub` - it shows line `import csv_sniffer`

So after `python setup.py install` you should test `import csv_sniffer`
instead of `import pandas_csv_sniffer`. And this works on my computer.