# Clone Repo into Local Repo and Install Package via Pip via Local Repo

Tags: python, github

I am a Python and Github novice. However, I'd like to run some code available on Github. My understanding is that I need to:

"First, clone this repo, cd into the local repo, and install via pip from your local repo"

Can someone provide the perquisite and requisite steps for executing:

- (1) cloning the repo into local repo.
- (2) and pip installing the package via the local repo.

I have only ever previously installed packages through the terminal, so the Github phase is new to me.

https://github.com/lucasimi/tda-mapper-python

All help would be appreciated on prerequisites and requisites.

Thank you

Comment: You can follow the selected answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch.

Comment: Hi @ cao-nv. Thanks for you feedback. Are you saying something like: pip install git + https://github.com/lucasimi/tda-mapper-python.git?

Comment: Sure, if you want to install from a default branch, just ignore the part from @.

Comment: Hi @ cao-nv. When I try: "pip install git github.com/lucasimi/tda-mapper-python.git" in the terminal, I get a warning. Cannot unpack file. Any tips to overcome this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*cloning the repo into local repo* - You need to have git install, you can find this [here](https://git-scm.com/)

*and pip installing the package via the local repo* - If you have Python installed recently, you should have **pip** to install Python packages

I don't know if you're using a Windows or a Linux like machine, if Linux, just follow the commands, if Windows, I'd recommend a proper terminal, at least the git bash that you can find and install [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

You're right with the steps, I'll attach the code, according to each one of those:

1. clone repo

```bash
git clone https://github.com/lucasimi/tda-mapper-python
```

2. cd repo

```bash
cd tda-mapper-python
```

3. create virtual environment (recommended)

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
```

If windows:

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

4. Activate venv

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

(You'll see **(venv)** on top of path)

5. Install dependencies

```bash
pip install .
```

Comment: Thanks @vgenovpy. That's very thorough and helpful; thank you. May I ask the steps for a Mac, please?

Comment: Hallo! Don't worry, if you're using a Mac all these commands will apply for you too ;)

I use iterm2 - https://iterm2.com/ but this is not needed

If the answer solves your issue please accept it and upvote it :) I'll appreciate that

Comment: Thank you @ vgenovpy. I'll try all the steps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again @ vgenovpy. Very new to this. So much so I had to download MacPorts first. Thank you for the detailed steps. Much appreciated

Comment: I've never heard of it, but it seems that's like homebrew. I think that's a more common option, but whatever fits your needs!

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask @vgenovy, how the code is extracted when the cd is given? So for example, at the bottom of this page there is a cd: cd 02_tweet_disaster" How do I extract this code so that I can see it on a Jupyter notebook?https://github.com/Robotmurlock/TDA-Mapper

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use Jupiter, so I can't help you with that. If you're looking for running the last part you gotta
1. cd
2. create a requirements.txt with the dependencies that the owner had listed
3. run pip install -r requirements.txt (always with venv activated)
4. python3 main.py for running the code.