# Python match case syntax error(not a version problem)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, cython, cythonize

I am using python match case statement in my python project. To test it, I am building a image with docker file, with python:3.12.2-slim-bullseye as base image, and installing python3 during build process.I have verified that the python version which gets installed during build is 3.10.12.Also I have a setup.py file which uses cython to build python files into .so files.

While building the image, cython throws error on **match** syntax, as I said, I have verified that python version being installed is 3.10.12 and more over I built a dummy image which has python 3.10.12, and went inside container and tested with a sample python file with match syntax and it works perfectly fine.But while building the files with Cython it is failing..Please if anyone has any idea please help me out.
I am a fresher and working on this big project, Cython was new to me.
[Syntax error shown while cythonizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93SF3.png)

[Cython version I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVOgo.jpg)

Comment: what version of cython are you using ? some of the older versions did not support the match-case syntax

Comment: Hi, so after installing python while building image, i am doing pip3 install Cython, it's installing latest version, I have checked Pypi

Comment: @KaranShishoo, are you aware of any cython version that implemented match case syntax ?

Comment: I was referring to the patama branch that is mentioned in the answer, I forgot that it was not an official release and still in an experimental branch

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't yet supported in any Cython release (as of my knowledge cutoff of 27 March 2024, i.e. today).

The [patma-preview branch](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/patma-preview) does contain a complete implementation so you can check that branch out and use it. However it's a large and basically unreviewed chunk of code so use it at your own risk. It'll be gradually merged into a release as it gets reviewed.

[pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch) shows you how to install from a branch.

If you want to track it, the relevant Cython issue is https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4029 (note that commenting "me too" on the issue *is not* a helpful contribution so please don't do that. Reporting any bugs you find in the branch would be useful though).